# How to setup custom number format for Year and isoweeknumber like "YY'WW"

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have below problem. I am putting below function in my custom number format for x axis of chart. It works for Years and Mohths but when I choose Weeks, then it is changing my date into `YY'WW` (Year'Week) format.

Can you please help me on this, if you have an idea?
you need to change only in `Parameters!vTimeScaleUnit.Value="Weeks","yy'WW"`  code.

```
=switch(Parameters!vTimeScaleUnit.Value="Years","yyyy",Parameters!vTimeScaleUnit.Value="Months","MM"&"/"&"yy",Parameters!vTimeScaleUnit.Value="Weeks","yy'WW")
```

Comment: Thanks Unheilig for editing my question.

Comment: I think SSRS doesn't support yy'ww format directly. However you can create a custom date format using expressions like Format and Datepart in SSRS

Comment: I know Prasaz, May you please tell me the otherway round that how can I achive the same.

Comment: Do we have any otherway round of this ?